# mobile scan and recognize image for iphone

Tags: iphone, image-processing, image-recognition

I've just been asked to build an iphone app that presents some typical static content.  However, some content is locked until the user takes the phone and scans an image of a logo that belongs to client's company.  If the scanned logo is valid, then the app unlocks more information to the content.

I haven't done any image recognition apps before.  Can someone tell me if

a) is it a trivial to implement (ie. just a few days) or is it substantial (ie. a few weeks)

b) which image recognition library to consider given that the current project is fairly small (just 4-5 screens of read-only content).

Comment: It can't just be a QR code? That would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Client asked for it to be a logo, becaus they are a credit card company and wnat to promote themselves.

Comment: I see. Well I only really know enough about the topic to say that it's non-trivial, but I can point you towards http://opencv.org

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion.  Researching now!